# An unexpected hang in multithreaded application

Tags: c++, mutex, deadlock

I am developing a simple bank system. One of the functions I implemented is **doTransaction**.
Simplified, it looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

const int N = 1000;
int accounts[N];
std::vector<std::mutex> mutexes(N);

int doTransaction(int from, int to, int amount) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_from(mutexes[from]);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_to(mutexes[to]);

    if (accounts[from] < amount) return -1;
    accounts[from] -= amount;
    accounts[to] += amount;

    return 0;
}
```

Despite the fact the function seems to be simple, sometimes the execution of this function hangs.
I have already spent a large amount of time trying to solve this problem. I think, there is some kind
of **deadlock** in my code.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Based on your currently posted code, the only problem I can see is that the correct way to lock multiple mutexes is to use `std::scoped_lock`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you can get is the case when you have called two methods in parallel, and first one is doTransaction(1, 2, 100) and second one is doTransaction(2, 1, 100). You can use hierarchical locking to avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_from(mutexes[from]);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_to(mutexes[to]);
```

The first line can succeed and obtain the lock (e.g. lock 10) and then attempt to get the second lock (e.g. lock 20).

However since this function can be called from different threads, if there are two transactions such as (10->20) and (20->10) that occur at the same time. Then one thread could hold lock 10, waiting for lock 20 while the other holds lock 20 waiting for lock 10.

And also if there are three transactions e.g. (10->20), (20->30) and (30->10) on three separate threads, then there is a possibility each thread locks the 'lock_from' mutex but fails to obtain the 'lock_to' mutex.